# Dual Processor Server CPU Temperature

Tags: cpu, xeon

I am running an application to monitor my CPU temperatures and I am noticing that Processor #1 is showing warmer than #0 by about 10 degrees C. My workstation (Dell T5500) has a CPU on the motherboard itself, and one on an optional riser board. Which one of these would be referred to as Processor 0 and 1?

Also, the server contains 2 X5680s. Is 85 degrees C under maximum load a bad temperature reading for this processor (this is for the warmer CPU)? I am thinking I may need to redo the thermal paste on it.

Comment: I've a Mac Pro does exactly the same thing - the first one to get the air runs cooler, the one behind it, warmer. Two X5690's. How's your airflow configged? `prochot`, btw on mine is 92°C.

Comment: I had this issue once, and I stopped one fan with my finger to see which CPU's temperature increased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A thermal differential like this is actually not unusual on many tower-style multi-CPU systems.  In essence, outside (cool) air flows over the heatsink for one of the CPU's first (in your case the one in socket 0), and then over the other one.  Because the air is warmer when it flows over the second heatsink, it ends up not absorbing as much heat from that heatsink, so it doesn't cool that processor as efficiently.

However, in yoru case, you've got an easier way to tell which socket is socket 0, namely just look at the motherboard.  When you've got these complicated optional riser board configurations, the socket on the motherboard is *always* socket 0.

As far as temperatures, 85 degrees celsius is a bit high (Intel CPU's are designed to run hot safely, but 85 is *really* close to the thermal throttling point for most Intel CPU's), but I doubt that redoing the thermal paste will help much unless you get *really* nice thermal paste and make sure to properly clean both the package and the heatsink.  Even then, I doubt it will have much direct impact (maybe 5 degrees if you're lucky).  You're probably going to get much better results by getting a better heatsink or improving the airflow through the case.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I got a Dual xeon and i'm worried about the temperature. The sensor says 44° Celcius, Mainboard says more temperature above 70°C and I took the temperature with an electronic thermometer and said 36°C. Im using windows 10. HWMonitor says the following:
[image: screen_monitor]
Is everything allright?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1128924)